# Framework/GetAppCredential.xaml usage issue using the Robotic Enterprise Framework

Tags: rpa, uipath-studio

Please let me know what this error means and how to go about fixing it. I’m just a beginner in RPA who needs help. Thanks in advance.
“Framework/GetAppCredential.xaml: For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document. To enable DTD processing set the DtdProcessing property on XmlReaderSettings to Parse and pass the settings into XmlReader.Create method.”

I have a Windows 10 PC, I tried shutting down Webroot Secure Anywhere, which didn't work.

Here's further detail

```
Error: System.Xml.XmlException: '>' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '='. Line 70, position 90.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String[] args)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowUnexpectedToken(String expectedToken1, String expectedToken2)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseAttributes()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElement()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
   at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(String uri, LoadOptions options)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(String uri)
   at UiPath.Studio.Plugin.Workflow.Document.XamlDocumentReader.ReadAsync(String path)
   at UiPath.Studio.Core.Services.PersistableServiceBase`3.GetFactoryByPath(String path)
   at UiPath.Studio.Core.Services.PersistableServiceBase`3.ResolveFactory(OpenInformation openInfo)
   at UiPath.Studio.Core.Services.PersistableServiceBase`3.OpenAsync(OpenInformation openInfo)
   at UiPath.Studio.Shell.ViewModels.Project.Behaviors.FileProjectItemBehavior.ExecuteOpenAsync(IFileSystemProjectItemViewModel item)
   at UiPath.Studio.App.Desktop.MVVM.Commands.TaskCommand`3.Execute(TExecuteParameter parameter, Boolean ignoreCanExecuteCheck)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__140_0(Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler), HResult -2146232000
```

Thanks appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Is this on the advanced training? What part exactly are you trying to do as that error could cover a lot of different sections

Comment: I was working on the advanced portion. The Calculator Security Hash. When I tried to do a project validation I got that error.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like your GetAppCredential.xaml file may be bad containing possible syntactical error. You may have to contact whomever you got this from and possibly update the file with a good one!